# SSMS 2012 Results Pane nor working at all

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have tried everything assigning shortcuts, resetting keyboard, adding button by customizing but result pane is not showing up, even after adding its button and clicking on it.

Am I doing something wrong or is there some other bug?

Comment: Do you see Results/Messages at the bottom!? If so, use the slider!

Answer (score 0):

You might be affected by a known issue, detailed here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/2860024

Essentially, you may be experiencing a corrupted .vssettings file for SQL Server Management Studio.  When you press Ctrl+R, you might see the following message in the status bar "(Ctrl+R) was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord…"

If this describes your issue, the fix is to reset the default keyboard mapping scheme:

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio.
2. On the menu bar, click Tools, and then click Options.
3. In the tree-view pane on the left side of the dialog box, click Keyboard.
4. Click Reset to reset the default keyboard mapping scheme.
5. In the dialog box that appears, click Yes.
6. Click OK.